# Attach fan through fanless PoE hat?

Tags: pi-4, poe

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 in a CanaKit case w/ [fan](https://www.canakit.com/raspberry-pi-fan.html).

I am attempting to install the fanless variant of the [Uctronics model U6109 PoE hat](https://www.uctronics.com/poe-hat-for-raspberry-pi-4-uctronics-mini-power-over-ethernet-expansion-board-for-raspberry-pi-4-b-3-b.html), but it covers and uses the gpio pins that I previously had the fan connected to.

The pins do not stick up out of the hat for the ones that it "uses" - at least not past being barely palpable (if I remove heatsinks from the RPI board.)

How do I connect the existing fan while using this fanless PoE hat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "HAT" appears to have pads which expose the "hidden" pins - just use these!

Install a 6 pin (or 8 pin for extra Gnd) header on the 8 pads on the left of the board.